# Using multiple anyOf inside oneOf

Tags: json, schema, jsonschema

I wanted to create a schema where I will be having multiple objects inside "oneOf" which will be having many objects in anyOf format where some of the keys can be of required type(this part works) 
My schema :-

```
{
    "description": "schema v6",
    "type": "object",
    "oneOf": [
    {
    "properties": {
    "Speed": {
      "items": {
        "anyOf": [
          {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/speed"
          },
          {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/SituationType"
          }
        ]
      },
      "required": [
        "speed"
      ]
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false
        }
      ],
      "definitions": {
        "speed": {
          "description": "Speed",
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "SituationType": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "Situation Type",
          "enum": [
            "Advice",
            "Depend"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
```

But when I'm trying to verify this schema but i'm able to authenticate some incorrect values like

```
    {
      "Speed": {
        "speed": "ABC",//required
        "SituationType1": "Advisory1" //optional but key needs to be correct
      }
    }
```

correct response which i was expecting was

```
    {
      "Speed": {
        "speed": "1",
        "SituationType": "Advise" 
      }
    }
```

Comment: I'm afraid you've falled into a common trap. `additionalProperties` cannot "see through" `anyOf` or any `...Of` keywords. I'll explain further in an answer.

Comment: Actually, you've conflated a few issues! No worries, here to help =]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to set the schema type correctly, otherwise implmentations may assume you're using the latest JSON Schema version (currently draft-7).

So, in your schema root, you need the following:

```
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
```

Second, `items` is only applicable if the target is an array.
Currently your schema only checks the following:

> If the root object has a property of "Speed", it must have a key of
>   "speed". The root object must not have any other properties.

And nothing else.

Your use of `definitions` and how you reference them is probably not what you intended.

It looks like you want `Speed` to contain `speed` which must be an integer, and optionaly `SituationType` which must be a string, limited by enum, and nothing else.

Here's the schema I have based on that, which passes and fails correctly based on your given example data:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "Speed": {
          "properties":{
            "speed": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/speed"
            },
            "SituationType": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/SituationType"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "speed"
          ],
          "additionalProperties": false
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  ],
  "definitions": {
    "speed": {
      "description": "Speed",
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "SituationType": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "Situation Type",
      "enum": [
        "Advice",
        "Depend"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You need to define the properties for `Speed`, because otherwise you can't prevent additional properties, as `additionalProperties` is only effected by adjacent an `properties` key. We are looking to created a new keyword in draft-8 to support this kind of behaviour, but it doesn't look like you need it in your example ([Huge Github issue in relation](https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/issues/556)).

Adding `additionalProperties` false to the `Speed` schema now prevents other keys in that object.

I SUSPECT that given your question title, there may be more schema at play here, and you've simplified it for this question. If you have a more detailed schema with more complex issues, I'd be happy to help also.

Comment: You can test your JSON Schema validation against JSON data using https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/